# Testing Paperclip Attachment Filesize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, shoulda

If I wanted to test the file-size of a Paperclip attachment unconditionally I could just use the standard matchers included:

```
it { should validate_attachment_size(:image).less_than(10.megabytes) }
```

However I don't want the attachment to be a requirement. Therefore I only want to test the attachment size if there is an attachment.

I can implement this using:

```
validates_attachment_size :image, less_than: 10.megabytes,
                          if: Proc.new {|model| model.image.exists?}
```

However, this causes the assertion to fail:

```
1) NewsItem should validate the size of attachment image
   Failure/Error: it { should validate_attachment_size(:image).less_than(10.megabytes) }
   Attachment image must be between  and 10485760 bytes
   # ./spec/models/news_item_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

As far as I can make it out, validations are tested by removing the `image`. However, given that I am using a Proc to avoid the validation if the `image` isn't present, this means the validation isn't run.

**How should I solve this?**

Comment: Not sure if it works with paperclip validations, but is it possible to just add allow_nil: true option to your validation? Theoretically, this should skip the validation if no attachment is provided.

Comment: @rails4guides.com It doesn't work with Paperclip validations unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I use this validation for Paperclip

```
# Paperclip
attr_accessible :imagem
has_attached_file :imagem, path: "public/produtos/:id/:style", url: "/produtos/:id/:style", default_url: 'missing/thumb.png'
validates_attachment_size :imagem, less_than: 10.megabyte
validates_attachment_content_type :imagem, content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
```

The default_url: set a default image, if the object has no image.